# PHP Does not allow me to upload 16MB file

Tags: php, joomla

I am trying to upload the 16 MB File, But my application does not upload this 17 MB file, As per my PHP.INI, i can upload till 20 MB.

As well i am not getting any respective error for upload failed.

when i hit upload button,  page gets load, but nothing happened.

**No Error,  nothing.**

in application top, i add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

How to catch this error sort of errors.

Comment: Check in your phpinfo() what is the max. file size for upload.

Comment: You say "nothing happened". What do you expect to happen? What is the code that is uploading?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP change the maximum upload file size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/php-change-the-maximum-upload-file-size)

Comment: my ini_get('upload_max_filesize'); Says 20 M, but iam trying just 16M file.    Errors like. " Unable to upload file due to input time exhausted somthing like that.

Comment: @mvp i already know my max file size, i dont want to set once again. i just want to upload just 16 MB file

Comment: "somthing like that" either post the exact error message, or dont even bother asking

Comment: @Dagon I want to throw error message while facing upload problem.

Comment: Try printing the file upload error message `$_FILES['your_file_input_name']['error']` - http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php Also take a look at the docs about common pitfalls when doing uploads http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.common-pitfalls.php

Comment: @Bharanikumar: if you are on Linux, you might be able to get some insight from `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or from `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Maybe it takes too long for the server to execute the script and the script times out. `Unable to upload file due to input time exhausted` change the `max_execution_time` or maybe `max_input_time`

Comment: @Sean i am not getting any error, even i used ['error'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides PHP ini max file size which you set already, there are more related variables which you should check:

```
upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 120M
max_execution_time = 6000
```

post_max_size is the total size of the post your browser is sending: thus it's the sum of all files that are attached to the form. Max execution time should also take the file size into consideration as most ADSL connections are slower uploading it could take as long as 5 minutes for some users to upload a 15mb file.

Don't exagerate: that would expose you to attacks/waste your bandwidth (not much damage there).

As per the errors, you should have them logged in your Apache error log: if the sum of file sizes exceeds post_max_size, the error will look like this:

```
[Fri Jul 05 17:38:09 2013] [warn] [client 157.16.35.224] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 5005313 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (5000000), referer: https://www.example.com/sef/path/rads/post/1?catid=1
```

Finally, make sure the space on disk and the user quota are not exhausted.  You will be able to determine which is the cause of the failing upload from the apache error_log.